# XLForm multi level selectors

Tags: ios, xlform

I'm working on a very old iOS project that is using [XLForm](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm). I have to support a dynamic screen flow such as this attached [image: picture]

As XLForms is no longer on active development, I thought of asking the question here.

I've tried using `XLFormOptionsObject` and using a `formSegueIdentifier` to fully go custom but has not been that much helpful. If anyone has experience on a similar type of implementation using XLForms, any advice is really appreciated.

Side question; 
I can intercept the Screen's C selection on Screen B using `formRowDescriptorValueHasChanged`, but how do I then manually pass that back to Screen A to update it's value?

---

Screen A
- Select Option >  (tap pushes to Screen B)

Screen B 
- Option 1 (tap selected option 1, pops and updates screen A row value)
- Option 2 (Same as option 1)
- Grouped Options >  (tap goes to screen C)
- Option 3 (Same as option 1)
...

Screen C
- Option 1 from Grouped options (tap selects option 1, pops Screen C & B to go to A and updates screen A's row value)
- Option 2 from Grouped options (same as above)
...